# Importing PNG for deep-learning Python

Tags: python, syntax, deep-learning, png

I am a novice coder, having been self-taught through codeacademy.  I am wondering what is the easiest way to import png files to python (2.7.14) with the goal of using these files in a deep-learning program.

So far I have tried these two codes:
    import scipy
    from scipy import misc
    import glob
    for image_path in glob.glob("/E:/_SAMM_Projects/gemini_hikai_DM_hack_complete/export/contact_frames/boat/*.png"):
        image = misc.imread(image_path)
        print image.shape
        print image.dtype

```
import scipy
from scipy import misc
import glob
import numpy
png = []
for image_path in glob.glob("/E:/_SAMM_Projects/gemini_hikai_DM_hack_complete/export/contact_frames/boat/*.png"):
    png.append(misc.imread(image_path))

im = np.asarray(png)

print "importing done...", im.shape
```

based off templates I have found online, both do not seem to work

Comment: What deep learning program? Is the neural network pre trained? [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see [fast.ai](http://www.fast.ai/)

Comment: the network is not pre-trained I will hopefully be training it with the png files if I can figure out how to get them into python

Answer (score 0):

In the context of deep learning, I understand that you would like to read an image into a numpy array so you can use deep learning models (such as ConvNet) on it.
I suggest using OpenCV for your purpose.

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("yourimg.png")
```

Comment: which version of opencv is compatible with the 32-bit Python 2.7.14? Every time I try to download the module I get an error message saying "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application." Ive tried a bund of the 2.x versions and none seem to be compatible with my version of Python